# GAE slowness with external MySQL DB

Tags: google-app-engine

I have a Java GAE hobby project utilizing a MySQL DB. I have been using Google's own CloudSQL, but am exploring switching to a cheaper, external MySQL host (Hostinger) for cost reasons.

When I am running the application locally, though still against the new remote MySQL host, the application runs quickly and responsively, just as it did with Google's CloudSQL (both locally and deployed). However whenever I deploy it to the GAE servers, it runs incredibly slow, and from looking at the logs its clear the time is in the DB requests (just reads/selects - no writes at this time).

Is there something inherently slow about GAE applications connecting to external/non-CloudSQL DBs? Anything that can be tweaked to improve performance?

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know there is nothing inherently slow when connecting to external services.

What can be generating this long time for connections from GAE to Hostinger is the distance between both datacenters. You can try deploying the GAE in a region closer to the hostinger datacenter and the time shall get reduced.

As a work around for this you can deploy the database in cloudSQL in a micro instance in one of the regions that apply for always [free tier](https://cloud.google.com/free/docs/gcp-free-tier) this way you can get the short time of response and it will still be cheap.

Comment: thanks for the response - I would expect there to be some slowdown due to distance of servers, but this is significant - at least an order of magnitude. And there isn't noticeable slowdown when I am running locally against the same Hostinger DB from my laptop and consumer Internet connection, which I would assume would be less than the GAE server.

Comment: in regards to the Google Cloud free tier, I reviewed the documentation on that, and I don't think it applies to the CloudSQL product? I definitely see the free tier kicking in on the GAE charges on my invoices, as well as my usage of the Google Maps API, but I don't see it being applied to the CloudSQL product. Or is there a way around that?

Comment: when you are creating a CloudSQL after choosing the DB manager you can show the configuration option and change the machine type to a db-f1-micro which are the free tier machines. It counts as free tier because this part is charged as the compute engine, so this machine applies for the 750 free hours a month. The other important step to keep it free is to disable the Auto Storage Increase.